# Error compiling litecoin clone, boost error

Tags: bitcoind, development, compiling

I am trying to clone litecoin for practice and for some reason this time around my build system isn't working right.

Here is the error I am having after trying to compile my clone AND litecoin 8.7.4 source

```
bitcoinrpc.cpp:984:52:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:38:18: error: no matching function for     call to ‘call_once(boost::once_flag&, void (*&)())’
     call_once(flag,func);
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:20:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:17,
             from util.h:24,
             from bignum.h:12,
             from main.h:8,
             from wallet.h:13,
             from init.h:8,
             from bitcoinrpc.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:121:15: note: candidate: template<class Function, class ... ArgTypes> void boost::call_once(boost::once_flag&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T>, boost::detail::thread_move_t<Args>...)
   inline void call_once(once_flag& flag, BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF(Function) f, BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF(ArgTypes)... args)
           ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:121:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:17:0,
             from util.h:24,
             from bignum.h:12,
             from main.h:8,
             from wallet.h:13,
             from init.h:8,
             from bitcoinrpc.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:38:18: note:   mismatched types ‘boost::detail::thread_move_t<T>’ and ‘void (*)()’
     call_once(flag,func);
              ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:35:13: note: candidate: template<class         Function> void boost::call_once(Function, boost::once_flag&)
inline void call_once(Function func,once_flag& flag)
         ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:35:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:38:18: note:   cannot convert ‘func’   (type ‘void (*)()’) to type ‘boost::once_flag&’
     call_once(flag,func);
              ^
make: *** [obj/bitcoinrpc.o] Error 1
```

Could someone please let me know what this is? I tried an issue and change a line in rpcrawtransaction.cpp

```
<const CScriptID &>
```

to

```
<CScriptID>
```

and also tried code snippet from feathercoin, both unsuccussful.

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could help get my system buildable again.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, sorry, I got past that part. I had clang as the compiler from update-alternatives, had to switch back to gcc. Currently compiling right now hopefully no more errors.